# How can I convert a CSV file to XLSM while renaming the file from the file path?

Tags: excel, vba

Another user greatly helped me with this but I am stuck on a few parts.
The purpose of the macro:
The purpose is to take the fifth element number in the current file path then rename the file with that number and a string following it. Then I want to convert it to CSV from XLSM

The comments I have outlined explain what each block code's description is. I am not sure how to change it so that I need not to use CONST since I want to find a variable that is found at run-time and const only uses compile-time.

- Const original is meant to be assigned the current workbook. I do not want a hardcoded file path in the macro.
- Ensuring that the xlsm copy is left alone but renamed so that it matches XLSM
- There will be a CSV copy and a XLSM copy
- The file path that I have been testing on is R:\3.0  Projects\2.0  Current Projects\2021 JOBS\999111-DO-Customer-Description\2.0  Estimate\2.7  Final Estimates\FoundationImport-TMP-IFI-REV12.XLSM
- I want the final file to be " R:\3.0  Projects\2.0  Current Projects\2021 JOBS\999111-DO-Customer-Description\2.0  Estimate\2.7  Final Estimates\999111import-TMP-IFI-REV12.XLSM

I appreciate your guys help greatly!

```
Function getName(pf): getName = Split(Mid(pf, InStrRev(pf, "\") + 1), ".")(0): End Function
```

```
Sub Snippet()
Const Original      As String = "R:\3.0 Projects\2.0 Current Projects\2021 JOBS\999111-DO-Customer-Description\" & _
                                "2.0 Estimate\2.7 Final Estimates\FoundationImport-TMP-IFI-REV12.XLSM"
'Original = getName(ActiveWorkbook.FullName)

Dim Ext             As String           ' file extension
Dim Fn              As String           ' file name
Dim Path            As String           ' file path
Dim Ffn             As String           ' full file name
Dim Sp()            As String
Dim CSVfile
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Foundation Budget Template")


' extracts number from 5th element and applies to file name
Sp = Split(Original, "\")
Fn = Sp(UBound(Sp))
Sp(7) = Split(Sp(4), "-")(0) & "import-TMP-IFI-REV12"
Ffn = Join(Sp, "\")
MsgBox "Original Ffn: " & Original & vbCr & vbCr & _
       "Changed 5th element: " & Ffn
       
'Convert file from XLSM to CSV
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=CSVfile, FileFormat:=xlCSV, local:=True

' append a file name to path
Sp = Split(Path, "\")
Fn = "My File Name" & "." & Ext
ReDim Preserve Sp(UBound(Sp) + 1)
Sp(UBound(Sp)) = Fn
Ffn = Join(Sp, "\")
MsgBox "Full File Name = " & Ffn



End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You have a better chance of finding someone to help you if you make an effort to reduce the argle-bargle to a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). TL;DR What are you trying to do? What have you tried so far? What specific obstacles have you encountered?

Comment: You cannot use `Const` for any value which is determined at *run-time* - you can only use values which are known at *compile-time*.  FYI I would also avoid the "everything on one line using `:`" approach you use for `getName` - it makes your code difficult to scan and debug.

Comment: @timwilliams Const is simply what I used to achieve my results but I want to see how I would set it up for compile-time as you suggested. I'll change getName. I appreciate your advice.

Comment: You can use `ThisWorkbook` to refer to the workbook where the code is running, and use its `.Name`, `.Path` properties as appropriate